# Phpstorm eap does not open

Tags: java, phpstorm

Today morning I made a normal update of my Xubuntu machine and after that, Phpstorm EAS doesn't open anymore. I thought that was a jdk matter, although I can't assure jdk was updated too. So I've downgraded from jdk8 to jdk7, but the problem persists.

My java -version output is

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

When I run phpstorm.sh I get the message

[YourKit Java Profiler 2014 build 14112] Log file: /home/csantos/.yjp/log/WebIde90-22725.log

The `tail` for `WebIde90-22725.log` is

```
14112 - 2.341: SP: pinned org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLConfigurationException
14112 - 2.347: SP: pinned org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException
14112 - 2.378: SP: pinned org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityScanner$1
14112 - 2.430: SP: pinned java.net.BindException
14112 - 2.757: SP: pinned java.net.SocketTimeoutException
14112 - 2.766: vmDeath: 1
14112 - 2.766: vmDeath: 2
14112 - 2.766: vmDeath: 3
14112 - 2.766: vmDeath: 4
14112 - 2.766: vmDeath: OK
```

Can someone help me? I'm stucked with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue. 
use "ps -A |grep java" to find java process id, then "kill xxxx" to kill the running process.

Answer (score 0):

I found that there was a java 8 process running already after I've downgraded from java 8 to java 7. After killing that process Phpstorm back to run accordingly.